# Using JQuery Vector Map to load svg file

Tags: svg, jvectormap

I'm using JQuery Vector Map to load an svg file but I'm getting the following

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of undefined
```

In fact the problem is that it is not being able to read from the svg file. Does someone know what needs to be done for  `$('#africa').vectorMap();` to read it.

```
<html>
            <head>
                    <title>Testing Map</title>
                    <script src="jquery.vector-map/jquery-1.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
                    <link href="jquery.vector-map/jquery.vector-map.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
                    <script src="jquery.vector-map/jquery.vector-map.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
                    <script  type="text/javascript">
                            $(function()
                            {
                                    $('#africa').vectorMap();
                            });
                    </script>
            </head>
            <body>
                 <div id="africa">
                    <embed src="africa.svg"/>
                 </div>
            </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't just use SVG file to be able to render Africa map. Soon I'm going to release new jVectorMap site, where many new maps, converted from GIS data, will be available. I work on it here https://github.com/bjornd/jvectormap-site.